# Python two lists previous indexes comparison does not work

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two lists, a and b. I am trying to find a,b where for example b[-1] > a[-1] and b[0] < a[0]. So basically if you imagine that a and b list are lines on the chart then I am looking for crossings. I am not sure why, but the code I wrote shows only first crossing correctly, next one does not fill the condition.

Here is the code:

```
a = [19, 17, 12, 8, 7, 10, 13, 24, 36, 56, 68, 73, 78, 86, 88, 84, 80, 73]
b = [22, 19, 11, 5, 3, 7, 11, 21, 30, 54, 62, 71, 75, 84, 86, 90, 85, 77]

for i,j in zip(a,b):

    if a[a.index(i) - 1] < b[b.index(j) -1]:
        if a[a.index(i)] > b[b.index(j)]:
            print(a[a.index(i)],b[b.index(j)])
```

Output:

```
12 11
13 11


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

So 12 11 are correct because 17 < 19, but 13 11 are not correct because 10 > 7

Appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: You have to test both conditions simultaneously: `if a[a.index(i) - 1] < b[b.index(j) -1] and a[a.index(i)] > b[b.index(j)]:` - but you should not use `index` here, your code would fail if there are duplicate values in a list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think that's pretty much the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to repeated element in list b

this is my solution without using index.

```
a = [19, 17, 12, 8, 7, 10, 13, 24, 36, 56, 68, 73, 78, 86, 88, 84, 80, 73]
b = [22, 19, 11, 5, 3, 7, 10, 21, 30, 54, 62, 71, 75, 84, 86, 90, 85, 77]

c = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
for i,j in enumerate(c):
    if c[i-1][1] > c[i-1][0] and c[i][1] < c[i][0]:
        print(*j)
```

Output:

```
12 11
```